# virtual com port using stm32l053r8 cube libaries in keil (via USB to virtual com port)

Tags: stm32

How to display a string from stm32l053r8 nucleo using cube libraries in keilv5 (via USB to virtual com port)

```
    if( HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK)  
         return 0; 
    if (HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc, (uint32_t*)ADC1ConvertedValues, 2048) != HAL_OK)  
     // return 0;  
    temp=HAL_ADC_GetValue   ( &hadc );

    need to display the temp value through usb in virtual com port (teraterm)
```